# Streamlit: How to add proper citation with source content to chat message

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm currently building a RAG (Retrieval Augmented Generation) Chatbot in Streamlit that queries my own data from a Postgres database and provides it as context for GPT 3.5 to answer questions about my own data.

I have got the basics working already (frontend and backend). Now I also want to display the sources used nicely. I already finished the backend part. It returns a list of dictionaries with the following format:

```
{"id": 1, "file_name": "my_file.pdf", "url_name": "", "content": "my content", "origin": "pdf"}
```

Some documents are actual files and therefore the "url_name" is "" and sometimes the source is an actual website. In that case "url_name" would be: "www.my_website.com"

In order to display websources nicely I found the streamlit-extras library which has a nice feature to display mentions:

```
from streamlit_extras.mention import mention
mention(label=f"{file_name}", url=url_name)
```

It displays a clickable text with an icon. The url opens in another tab:
[image]

Now this does not really work for my non url documents. In that case I need something to show the actual text of the document. But I don't want to do it inline. **I want something like this:**

[image]

The Microsoft Azure App chatbot example provides the user the option to click on a source which will then show the content of the document on the right side of the page.

I want to copy this behaviour by providing a **selecatable text element that will expand the right sidebar in streamlit and display the text within this sidebar**.
Unfortunately I have no idea how I can accomplish this as there is no way to make a selectable text that can expand the sidebar and fill it with content as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to serve the PDF via Flask/FastAPI and then use its link in your `mention(label=f"{file_name}", url=url_name)`.

The good news here is that most browsers will display the PDF on a specific page when it is provided. For example, if you go to https://arxiv.org/pdf/2401.00107.pdf#page=4, you will automatically land on page 4. So, in the simplest implementation, your `url_name` would be something like this: `http://yourdomain.com/path_to_pdfs/{source["file_name"]}#page={source["page"]}`.

Now, if you want to display the PDF in your Streamlit app, you would need to embed it somehow with that link. You can use an HTML iframe as mentioned here: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/rendering-pdf-on-ui/13505/21. Another option is to use `st.components.v1.iframe`: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/aligning-st-components-v1-iframe/35885/4.